# C#: generic method constraint on subclassed types

Tags: c#, generics, constraints

I have two kinds of base classes:

```
public class Parent { }
public abstract class Child : Parent 
{
    string ChildKey { get; set; }
}
```

Derived from Parent, there are many kids:

```
public class Kid1 : Parent { public string Name { get; set; } }
public class Kid2 : Parent { public long Number { get; set; } }
...
```

and also many Children as a special group of Childs with extra properties:

```
public class Child1 : Child { public string Street { get; set; } }
public class Child2 : Child { public long Account { get; set; }}
```

Now I have two generic repository classes where the "Special One" acts more specific on the extra properties by using an additional filter:

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : Parent 
{ 
    public IEnumerable<T> GetAll() { return something; }
}
public class ChildRepository<T> : Repository<T>, IChildrenRepository<T> where T : Child 
{ 
    public override IEnumerable<T> GetAll() { return base.GetAll().Where(x => x.ChildKey == "y"); }
}
```

with the interfaces:

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : Parent
{ IEnumerable<T> GetAll(); }
public interface IChildRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : Child { }
```

I also need the type safety of the GetAll()-results.

Now I need a generic method to create the desired repository:

```
IRepository<T> GetRepository() where T : WhatConstraint
{
    if (typeof(Child).IsAssignableFrom(T))
        return new ChildRepository<T>();    // return 1
    return new Repository<T>();             // return 2
}
```

What is the correct constraint? return 1 needs Child-Constraint (which is wrong for return 2), saying that Type T cannot be used as type parameter in method since there is no implicit reference conversion from T to Child.

The T : Child-constraint is more precise in ChildRepository (and therefore useful, since I can rely on some properties). If I use the same T : Parent-constraint of the Repository, I have to type-check whether T is derived from Child all the times...

Are there any solutions to this?

Comment: Your design seems odd to me. You state "a `Parent` **has** kids and children", however by using inheritance (e.g. `class Kid1 : Parent`) you state "`Kid1` **is** a `Parent`, which surely makes no sense.

Comment: i guess children inherit from parents, oh thats my chuckle for the day

Comment: You can use `where T: Parent` anyway. A constraint doesn´t determine the actual type for `T`, but only which types *may* be used for `T`. Thus `GetRepository<Child>()` would be fine also, creating a `ChildRepository`. Having said this I can´t see any reason to even *have* a `ChilldRepository` at all, you could achieve the same via `GetRepository<Child>` which would return a new `Repository<Child>`.

Comment: The solution is to rebuild your design. but i dont know what is your main problem (not this XY problem) so i cant help.

Comment: You need to enhance your architecture which will solve all your problems, is that ok to change and post and answer or you need to solve it the way you posted? for ex : kid is inherting from parent which is wrong and must be changed.

Comment: whats the difference between kid and child? also whats the purpose of abstract class `Child`?

Comment: " If I use the same T : Parent-constraint of the Repository, I have to type-check whether T is derived from Child all the times" Eeeehm, no. If you´d have a `Repository<Child>` calls to `GetAll` will surely return strongly typed `Child`-instances. No need to type-check.

Comment: Can you please be more specific on what you mean by "where the "Special One" acts more specific on the extra properties:"? It´s hard to imagine as we can´t see any additional logic added on `Child` which does not exist in `Parent` already and how that should be hndled within your repo.

Comment: see above: Child has special properties which are relevant for GetAll()-Implementation. While the normal ParentRepository gets all of the records, the ChildRepository does additional filtering. You may ask: "Why should you do this?" The answer is: "Because I have to read some really weird and sick COBOL/ISAM-structures."

Comment: @Mate I´ve updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here is a detailed solution (which can be written shorter as well as less readable). Since Repository and ChildRepository have conflicting constraints (which is good for the repositories, but bad for GetRepository-factory), I cannot create the ChildRepository using new-keyword. I have to create this object via CreateInstance.

```
IRepository<T> GetRepository() where T : Parent
{
    if (typeof(Child).IsAssignableFrom(T))
    {
        Type childType = typeof(T);  // which is both, Parent and Child
        Type classType = typeof(ChildRepository<>);
        Type[] typeParams = { childType };
        Type repositoryType = classType.MakeGenericType(typeParams);
        return Activator.CreateInstance(resultType) as IRepository<T>;
    }
    return new Repository<T>();
}
```

Downside of this solution: More complex code analysis, unclear nullability of result, not really intuitive readable (especially existing constraints). But it works.